# How to check Today's Day and Search Files

Tags: find, date

Problem: I need to find out today's date and search a file which contain's today's date in the name. Also another file which contains Yesterday's date. 
I was able to do so by something like:

```
TODAY=$(date +"%m%d%Y")   
YESTERDAY=$(date --date="yesterday" +"%m%d%Y")
SNAPSHOT=SnapshotIR${YESTERDAY}\*.csv

for snapshotfile in $SNAPSHOT
do
        if [ -f "$snapshotfile" ]
        then
                SNAPSHOTFOUND="$snapshotfile"
          echo Snapshot Report $SNAPSHOTFOUND is available
```

But there is a condition here that, if today is Monday I have to check one file which has last Friday's date and another file which has Saturday's date in their names unlike Today and Yesterday.

Can anyone suggest.

Comment: Find out today's weekday name and implement your special condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name "*`date +%Y%m%d`*.*"
```

Finds files recursively, type f finds only files and name find only files that match the pattern. Using backticks `` you can add the date inline.

With date +%u you get the weekday number. If it is "1" then its Monday.

To check for last Friday and Saturday's dates, use --date

```
date --date="last Friday" +%Y%m%d
date --date="last Saturday" +%Y%m%d
```